# sumproduct with duplicates - only want first instance

Tags: excel-formula

I am using the following formula to return the data in a cell from looking up a row number.
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!R"&SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet2!S:S=Sheet3!D3),ROW(Sheet2!R:R)))

The sumproduct formula looks at the value in cell D3 and returns which row it is found on in Sheet2.  When there are more than one cells with the value in D3, the row numbers get added together.  How can I get it to return only the first instance if there is more than one cell with the lookup value?  I think I need rank or something, but am a little lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First INDIRECT is volatile and should be replaced with INDEX.

Second use AGGREGATE to return the lowest row number

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!R:R,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(Sheet2!S:S)/(Sheet2!S:S=Sheet3!D3),1))
```

Note: I left the full column References, but it is better practice to limit both `Sheet2!S:S` references to that of just the data set.  It will speed up the calculations.